# How to make J2SE as Server and J2ME as Client with Wi-Fi service?

Tags: java, java-me, client-server, wifi

i want to know what is the protocols to be used, how to implement these protocols in both j2se and j2me -> just the lib to be seen to know this.

Comment: Let us know what have you tried ?

Comment: I just want a reliable way to make connection between a mobile and a server to send and receive (files, images, data).

Comment: Read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318610/designing-a-mobile-web-server-and-client-for-traffic-compression)